# Непонятны некоторые фрагменты кода

Tags: c++

```
1    #ifndef __FIGURES_H
2    #define __FIGURES_H
3    
4     
5    class Figure{
6       int color;   
7    public:
8       Figure(int color) :
9         color(color) 
10        {}
11         
12        virtual double place() const = 0;
13         
14        struct Point{
15            int x;
16            int y;
17            Point(int x, int y):
18            x(x), y(y) 
19            {}
20        };
21    };
22    
23       ...
24    #endif
```

Если в 5-ой строке не указан спецификатор доступа то по умолчанию там имеется ввиду 
**public:int color;** ? 
Ещё не очень понятно что происходит на 8-10 и 14-20

Если не сложно расписать или сказать как это называется и где можно об этом почитать.

```
Figure(int color) :
  color(color) 
  {}
```

и

```
  struct Point{
      int x;
      int y;
      Point(int x, int y):
      x(x), y(y) 
      {}
  };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Доступ по умолчанию для класса — `private` (а для структуры — `public`). Таким образом, `color` объявлен как `private`.
2. В строках 14-20 объявляется внутренняя для класса `Figure` структура `Point`. Она находится в зоне действия `public`, поэтому «видна» снаружи. Это лишь объявление структуры `Point`, но не объявление поля типа `Point`. (Такого поля в структуре нету.) Вы можете использовать этот тип, например, объявляя переменные этого типа: `Figure::Point point;`.
3. В строках 8-10 приведена реализация конструктора, типичная для C++.

Распишем по строчкам:

```
Figure(int color) : // Конструктор принимает один параметр.
  color(color)      // Инициализация полей: для поля color вызывается конструктор
                    // с аргументом, равным аргументу color из конструктора. По
                    // стечению обстоятельств, их имена одинаковы.
  {}                // Больше конструктор ничего не делает.
                    // Это типично для конструкторов в C++: только инициализировать
                    // поля и всё.
```

Конструктор у `Point` выполнен в том же ключе, только он инициализирует 2 поля.

В конструкторе перед непосредственно телом конструктора кроме полей можно ещё инициализировать базовые классы. Но у `Figure`/`Point` базового класса нету, так что эта часть отпадает. Если базовые классы есть, а вы не прописали инициализатор, будет вызван конструктор базового класса без параметров (ну или тот, который может быть вызван без параметров).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.
Только с модификатором доступа по умолчанию не понятно, Вы уверены что здесь color объявлен как private? Если я прописываю private: int color; программа начинает работать не так, когда private не был написал, а при написании public или protected всё работает как надо.

Comment: @arukasa: Странно. [Цитирую](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> A class has default private accessibility for inheritance and members, a struct has instead a default public accessibility.

А что отличается? Не компилируется?

Comment: Пишет что не может обратиться к приватному члену, дело уже не в этом куске кода,а в целой программе, просто если private не прописан, то он к нему может обратиться. Либо я не совсем так понял и хочу уточнить в данном случаи: 
> int color; == Private:int color; ?

Comment: В данном случае должно быть то же самое, что и `private:` (с маленькой буквы). Покажите кусок кода, который перестаёт компилироваться, а?

Comment: > http://ideone.com/OXmWGy .h
> http://ideone.com/6JEF7q .cpp 32-34
> http://ideone.com/dnY4B7 .cpp

Comment: @arukasa: не компилируется <http://ideone.com/6JEF7q>, ругается на функцию `void Circle::output() const`, на то, что нельзя обращаться к `color`? Ну да, оно должно ругаться и в случае, если перед декларацией `int color;` внутри `class Figure` ничего нет, и в случае, если перед ним стоит `private:`.

---
Делайте так: http://ideone.com/r2Hp59

Comment: Всё понял свою ошибку,что-то затупил сильно. Спасибо Вам большое.

Comment: @arukasa: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

- Права доступа для объекта типа объявленного при помощи ключевого слова `class` - `private` и `public` - для `struct`
- Строки 7-10 - Это объявление (и определение) конструктора объектов класса `Figure` с параметром типа int (или любым, который можно привести int, т.к. не указано ключевое словов `explicit`). Конструктор ничего не делает кроме инициализации внутреннего поля color параметром конструктора (очень криво конечно сделано, но большинство компиляторов это схавает).
- Это объявление внутреннего типа объекта внутри класса `Figure`. Все поля публичные. Конструктор принимает два параметра типа int (или приводимым к int'у) инициализируя поля структуры. Тип `Point` доступен за пределами класса `Figure`.